# Display 3D data from radar on 2D HUD

Tags: matrix, lua, 3d, 2d, hud

I'm writing a script for game Stormworks in in-game Lua based microcontroller thingy. It can get bunch of stuff as an input, do whatever is in the script, and output it to whatever.
Currently, I have a Radar component that provides Azimuth, Elevation and Distance to objects in front of me, mentioned microcontroller and a HUD that sits in front of the player.

The idea is to take the data from the radar and display a point on the HUD exactly where the object that the radar is tracking. I've already experimented with displaying position of object from "top-down view" (aka drawing the world map on a screen and displaying a point on the location of the object, works pretty well and got myself familiar with trigonometry and a bit of matrices).

The problem is, how do I translate the angles and distance from Radar to a 2D screen in front of me that's using XYZ coordinate system.

I've tried:

- rotating the computed local XYZ coordinates of the object (local = radar is the origin point and the coordinates are distance from the radar) around the Y axis, that doesn't work
- using Homogenous Coordinates, which kind of didn't helped at all, just made it a bit simpler to understand. There was a formula however, that I've been told should work, but it doesn't. [See my post about this on math.stackexhange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4679166/rotating-matrices-to-display-data-from-radar-onto-a-hud). It also contains mathematical notations of what I'm trying to achieve, what I've tried and a tiny bit more information about the math

Here is the code I have written that is kind-of close but not really:

```lua
for i = 1, max_targets do
        if targets[i] then
            -- calculate radar's values in radians
            azi_rad = target_azi[i] * pi2
            ele_rad = target_ele[i] * pi2
            
            -- local "unrotated" values
            target_x_unrot = math.sin(azi_rad)
            target_y_unrot = math.cos(ele_rad)
            
            -- rotate the radar values around the roll and pitch
            target_x = ((target_x_unrot * math.cos(roll)) + (target_y_unrot * math.sin(roll))) * target_dst[i]
            target_y = (-(target_x_unrot * math.sin(pitch)) + (target_y_unrot * math.cos(pitch))) * target_dst[i]
    
            -- idk why those numbers are like this, but this is the least f.cky solution
            target_px = ((w/2) - target_x/2)
            target_py = (target_y/2)
 
            -- draw the point on the screen where the enemy should be
            screen.setColor(255, 0, 0)
            screen.drawCircle(target_px, target_py, 2)  -- target point
        
            target_count = target_count + 1 -- update target cnt
        end
    end
```

Many variations of the rotation were tried, I've tried rotating all coordinates around every axis (specifically Y), I've tried computing the intersection using `(x/z, y/z, 1)` but that seems to produce similar results to the matrix rotation.. Logically it makes sense to me to rotate the local coordinates around the Y axis, but apparently that is not the case.

I'm expecting to get a pointon the HUD that corresponds to "physical" in-game location of the object that the radar is tracking, no matter the approach angle and/or distance (obviously, if it's in the detection distance of the radar).